# font-weight: lighter" style does not seems to be working with lighter fonts in flying-saucer. Any solution?

Tags: pdf-generation, flying-saucer

I've included `OpenSans-Light.ttf` in source. If I added either `font-weight: lighter` or `font-weight: 200` it is not getting applied on PDF. Always the regular font style is getting applied.

Any solution/workaround would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

mPDF does not support multiple weights for a font face - just normal and bold

http://www.mpdf1.com/forum/discussion/1369/open-sans-problems-with-bold-font-weight/p1

Comment: ohh .. just noticed that this is _not_ link-only, sorry for my earlier comment :-)

Answer (score 2):

One workaround is to use `.light {font-family:Open Sans Light}`

Here's an example of what you get:
[image]

---

Another solution, which gives the same result is to use font-faces like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  src: url("font/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
  -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
  -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  src: url("font/OpenSans-Light.ttf");
  font-weight:200;
  -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
  -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
}
.normal{font-family:Open Sans;}
.lighter{font-family:Open Sans;font-weight:200}
```

Answer (score 1):

As said by @Lyuba Evdokimova `pdf generation engine` might not support all properties related to the given font.

I believe all of them works fine with `web_safe` fonts.
You can find more about them [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp).

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution, but it's a workaround.
You may use this CSS to replace for lighter font-weight:

> text-shadow: -0.06ex 0 currentColor, 0.06ex 0 currentColor!important